# Song transcription, almost done, three lines missing

Tags: translation

I'm trying to transcribe the poem that can be listened to at this URL : https://vimeo.com/48361321

I've almost finished but I can't manage to translate three bits of the song. Here's the text I made so far, with interrogation marks on the bits I can't translate, along with the times of the bits on the video :

```
This tiny person, too small for the bed, hidden under the covers,
eyes too big for his face, ??????????????????????????? (around 0:24)
unsmiling, unsharing, not happy, not angry, not sad, used to be my dad.

Alzeihmers, dementia, old cold age, bitter disappointment, disaster.

And me, I remember him as a child, hard-working, tender, gentle, very
kind, and funny, in his own way. He would get in his car, and forget the
car keys in the door, and then search all his pockets, and I would laugh,
I would laugh.

Now, smell of stale urine whiffs up as I lift the cover, gently pungent.
Reminds me of ????????????????????? (around 1:30)

He looks at me and then turns his face away.
I see the imperceptible pout,
I hear the tear that slips down his taut face. I see him say
"Why did you leave?" "What do you want from me now?"

Or is this voice is my own?

Don't you remember me, abbu ?
I was here a few months ago,
before I left again to my adventures of finding me, of finding you.

Your eyes were so vacant then. We held hands,
and your fingers rubbed my palm. Don't you remember at all?

Do you also wait for me, the way you are waiting for death?
It won't come by wishing. You know that.

I tried to lift him up,
To stuff some sickly sweet porridge down his throat.
Doing my part, showing, unshowing care.

He stiffens, raises a bony arm,
and with the power not matching the tender frame
Slaps me on the face, and goes limp again.

Short, sharp, ???????????????????? (around 3:12)
a tear slips down my stinging face,
a few seconds are forty years. And I lay him, gently back.

I wait for the grandmother's voice to say something.
There is no sound. Only my heart pounding. Pounding.

I finally take a breath. He knows I am here.
He knows I care. I know that so do I

My Daddy loves me This I know My daddy loves me I know...
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> **grey with the light**
>
> Reminds me of **old rose petals crushed**
>
> and with the power not matching the tender frame
>   *should be*
>   and with **a** power not matching the tender frame
>
> Short, sharp, **breath where it is, I'm shocked, stunned**

Nice poem, thanks for sharing it.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot, I'm glad you like the poem :)

Comment: http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1236/do-not-feed-the-bears